# Webpack not finding dynamically (js) added background images

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack

So I have been working on my portfolio page for a while now. I am using webpack after a short crash course from the docs and been learning as I run into roadblocks.

The first problem I noticed in this project was that nothing was seen in the dist folder, even though the CLI shows a successful build.

The main issue is that when I add CSS background images via js, it shows me a 404 error (it can't find the image files, although it is in the src directory). Checking through the console, it is obvious that the styles are being applied. 
[image: error]

(Everything else seems to be working fine; hence it's not my code error) 
[image: my page]
Hence I feel this a webpack problem, maybe something with file-loader, or style-loader
I did a great deal of troubleshooting for a couple of hours, even deleted and reinstalled node_modules folder

I would appreciate all contributions

Here is a link to the Github repo (if you've got more time to spare): [Github repo](https://github.com/stealthman22/StealthPortfolio)

Here is some code for what is going on:

**HTML**:

```
  <div class="hero">
        <time class="time"></time>
        <h1 class="greeting">
            <span class="greeting-js"> </span> I'm Joel
        </h1>
        <h2 id="description"> a web developer</h2>
    </div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.hero {

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    color: var(--text-sec);
}
```

**dynamicHero.js**:

```
const time = document.querySelector('.time');
const hero = document.querySelector('.hero');

const greetingJs = document.querySelector('.greeting-js');
const greeting = document.querySelector('greeting');



function setBg() {
    console.log(' I am Working')
    let today = new Date(),
        hour = today.getHours();

    //morning
    if (hour < 12) {
        hero.style.background = "url('./img/rippling-water-2257568 large.jpg')";
        greetingJs.textContent = 'Good Morning,'


    } else if (hour < 18) {
        hero.style.background = "url('./img/one-world-trade-center-under-cloudy-sky-during-daytime-161963.jpg)";
        greetingJs.textContent = 'Good Afternoon,'
    }
    else {
        hero.style.background = "url('./img/bonfire-burning-camp-campfire-1368382.jpg')"
        greetingJs.textContent = 'Good Evening'
    }
}


// Run functions
getTime();
addZero();
setBg();
```

**index.js**:

```
import './index.html';
import './style.css';
import './eyes';
import './dynamicHero';
```

**Webpack Config** (As you can see I commented out the clean webpack plugin, as it could have been the culprit for this behaviour):

```
//require plugins
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
// const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// modules
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',

    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // babel 
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        // load with html loader and then minimize
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            interpolate: true,
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        /*   new CleanWebpackPlugin({
              cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['dist']
          }), */
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
            ignoreOrder: false,
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
        },

    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
}
```

**Package.json**:

```
{
    "name": "stealthportfolio",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "My portfolio page.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/stealthman22/StealthPortfolio.git"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/stealthman22/StealthPortfolio/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/stealthman22/StealthPortfolio#readme",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
        "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.1.1",
        "webpack": "^4.41.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the file-loader plugin requires you to import your images in the JS rather than just specifying the URL in the CSS string.

```
import myImagePath from './img/rippling-water-2257568 large.jpg';

hero.style.background = `url(${myImagePath})`;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So does this mean I would have to import every image? because I would be using quite a lot. 
Is there possibly any approach that won't make things so **manual**? 
Maybe a way to import the entire image folder

Comment: It worked like a charm, but really having to do this one by one is already looking like an herculean task lol.

BTW "46.9k" repuatation is Waoooh

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth and I've not spent much time analysing it, the following line is missing an apostrophe:

hero.style.background = "url('./img/one-world-trade-center-under-cloudy-sky-during-daytime-161963.jpg)";

The apostrophe after .jpg.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does thank you. I am sure even if I got a solution, that will still have thrown me an error :)